# extjs column editor format the value of editor

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In a ext grid, I have a editor of a column as a textfield. The column datatype is datecolumn(I need this for time). I need to format the value from the column to the editor textfield as H:i

here is my code

```
xtype: 'datecolumn',
editor: {
    xtype: 'textfield'
},
dateFormat: 'H:i',
renderer: function (val){
    if (Ext.isDate(val)) {
    return Ext.util.Format.date(val, 'H:i');
}
return val;
}
```

I already tried setting renderer for the textfield, and also adding listeners. also tried in the beforeedit method, but no success.

Any tips?

Comment: Don't you think for the datecolumn you need datefield editor ?

Comment: I need the editor to show the value in this format "H:i"

Comment: You can configure datefield format for displaying as well as you do it for datecolumn

Answer (score 3):

Your editor should be a [`datefield`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date) and you should use the `format` config for both the [column](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Date-cfg-format) and the [editor field](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-format). There's no need to set a custom renderer function.

```
{
    xtype: 'datecolumn',
    format: 'H:i'        
    editor: {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        format: 'H:i'
    }
}
```